# jQuery traversing and finding textboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I am looping through elements in a table - say a hidden field of class "pmtos" - how do I get a reference to the text field (input) within the same cell in the table?

jQuery is:

```
 // Loop through each hidden field, which holds the outstanding amount
 $(".pmtos").each(function () {

        var os = $(this).val();
        //
        //find text box in same cell - and populate with some value
        //
        //

 });
```

Thank you for any guidance in getting this working.

Mark

Comment: You really need to make this question more concise.

Comment: Needs to be more descriptive

Comment: I have made this far more concise - thank you, Mark

Comment: @Mark - thank you - but it's not always going to be NewInvoiceViewmodel_0_PaymentReceived - it could be NewInvoiceViewmodel_22_PaymentReceived etc - thanks, Mark

Comment: Not sure if this is what you wanted (did it before your edit) http://jsfiddle.net/FZPbE/9/

Comment: Can you show the markup? I don't know if you mean same row, adjacent, child, etc.

Comment: `$(this).prev('.pmtallocated')` or `$(this).siblings('.pmtallocated')` - the latter is probably the better of the two as it doesn't rely on `.pmtallocated` coming immediately before `this` in the markup

Comment: Sorry, I posted before I saw your fiddle - which appears to work perfectly - if you post as the answer... - thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution to the question before it was edited (as requested):

```
$('#allocate').click(function () {
  var recd = parseFloat( $('#pmtRecd').val() );
     
  $('input.pmtallocated').each(function() {
    var value = parseFloat( $(this).parent().prev().text() );
    this.value = (recd >= value) ? value : recd;         
    recd = recd - this.value;

    if (recd == 0) {
      return false;
    }
  });  
});
```

Note: This doesn't rely on the hidden input. It takes the text from the `td` in the second column.

#### [Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FZPbE/9)

**To answer the question post-edit**

You can use `siblings('.pmtallocated')` or `prev('.pmtallocated')` to get the input. Using `siblings()` would probably be the better of the two as it doesn't rely on `pmtallocated` coming directly before `pmtos` in the markup:

`$(this).siblings('.pmtallocated').val()`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 // Loop through each hidden field, which holds the outstanding amount
 $(".pmtos").each(function () {

        var os = $(this);
        var cell = os.parent(); // gets the parent, i.e. the table cell
        var input = cell.find('input')[0];

 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this out. may works for you.

```
   $(".pmtos").each(function () {

            var os = $(this).val();
            var input = $(this).closest('td').find('input[type=text]');

     });
```

Comment: @MarkTait this will select both of the inputs (`pmtallocated` and `pmtos`)

Comment: @billyonecan - I see that now - can you suggest how to pick just a specific one?  Perhaps by class?  thank you.

Comment: @MarkTait see my comments on your question

Comment: Congratz Mark Tait . But the question was "find text box in same cell - and populate with some value" .. and the answer is not getting it from the same cell.. Just for my info.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `$(this).closest('input')`